# SSL site hosted in IIS shows certificate, but no such certificate is installed

Tags: ssl, certificate, https, iis

I have a problem that is really leaving me scratching my head. I'm hoping it's something simple I've overlooked.

I need to replace an expiring SSL server certificate on an IIS 7.5-hosted site on a Windows Server 2008 box. When I visit the site, the browser verifies the cert in question and shows the expected expiration date...so far, so good. Should be a simple, normal replacement....alas...

When I go to IIS to look for the certificate, it isn't there. In fact, the site's SSL bindings don't even *specify* a certificate, which makes me wonder how on earth it could support SSL for that site.

I've used the CertMgr interface to search for the cert...no joy. I've double-checked that the resolved hostname does, in fact, point to the IP address of the server in question, and it does. But there's absolutely *nothing* indicating the presence of the certificate I'm being told *is* being used to support the SSL binding for that site, even though IIS says there *isn't* one. Obviously, this makes no sense - or I'm just being dense and missing something obvious.

What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you are missing anything, if `netsh http show sslcert` doesn't show your certificate, then you are hitting the wrong server.

Comment: Thanks, @PeterHahndorf. I suspected that very thing - going to the wrong server - but was able to verify we were hitting the correct site. I have since surmised that some unknown corruption on the IIS side prevented it from *displaying* the certificate even though it was *using* it. I updated the expiring cert and installed it, and the updated cert was verified through the client browser, so the issue will, for now, remain a mystery.